# How to quit evil mode?

Tags: evil

My vim-using co-worker came by, and since he wanted to do something with files on my PC, I installed evil-mode to allow him to do this more efficiently (vim user trying to accomplish anything in emacs is a sad view). Now I've got a problem: I don't know how to quit evil-mode! I want to turn it off; how can I do that?

Answer (score 12):

You should also be able to `C-z` to enter normal emacs mode, and then another `C-z` to go back to evil.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I'm free! To exit evil-mode, you need to press `:` (so that you go into command mode, or whatever it's called), and input `evil-mode`, then RET. So, just input `:evil-mode` and press enter. Voila!

Comment: I just run `evil-mode`. `M-x evil-mode` toggles as expected. When you are in input-mode of vi (cursor is a vertical line instead of a rectangle) press `ESC` before `M-x evil-mode`.

Comment: @Tobias unfortunately it's not the same for me. Both in insert-mode and the other mode, M-x works like Delete.

Comment: If you want you can delete the `evil-mode-*` folder in your `~/.emacs.d/elpa` directory to remove it permanently.